# gate is not connected to sibling or parent module on omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am traying to create a network with "n" client nodes (chosen by the user)  connected to a centralized server

```
   simple serveur 
    {        
     gates:
     inout port[];
    }

   simple client
    {
    //  @display("i=device/pc");

     gates:
      inout port;
      }
      network networks
    {

        int nb;   
        submodules:
      n[nb]: client;
        server: serveur;

       connections :
        for i=0..nb-1 
        {   
         n[i].port <--> {  delay = 0.1ms; datarate = 100Mbps; } <--> server.port++ if uniform(0,1)<0.8;
        }

       }
```

But I got this error when I try to run the simulator:

> Gate 'networks.n[3].port$i' is not connected to sibling or parent module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OMNeT++` requires that all gates are connected. However, one can turn off the connectivity check for **all** gates by adding `allowunconnected` word after `connections`, so in your code should be:

```
   connections allowunconnected:
    for i=0..nb-1 
    {   
     n[i].port <--> {  delay = 0.1ms; datarate = 100Mbps; } <--> server.port++ if uniform(0,1)<0.8;
    }
```

Comment: i fixed the problème by moving " {  delay = 0.1ms; datarate = 100Mbps; }" and the condition too "if uniform(0,1)<0.8" becuz even when i add allowunconnected i got some nodes who r not connected to the server                    thank you :)